# My site not working properly in explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, comments

There is an error at my Wordpress-site (http://tornaia.com) when I use Internet Explorer. The drop-down menu isn't working, the comment fields are not working and everything is moved to the left.

I got a tip in the wordpress forum (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/my-site-not-working-properly-in-explorer?replies=12):

"You have some junk characters in front of the DOCTYPE and the IE8 conditional comment is broken, too, in header.php. Fix the code errors and display in IE should be OK. [Invalid] Markup Validation of tornaia.com - W3C Markup Validator. Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. " (link to the W3C Markup Validator: it's in the wordpress forum-link above)

I haven't managed to find out where or how these errors can be fixed (or if this is really the source of the problem). Maybe someone here can help me? That would be great.

(I can't get any more help from wordpress because my theme isn't a wordpress-theme anymore. The developer had it removed. So then the theme-developer said he would help me out, but so far no luck there.)

Thank you!

Comment: you are not including any css for IE browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this and implementing the stylesheets for IE:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style/css/IEsucks.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I taking into account the source from your site: it should look something like this.

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<title>La Tornaia - Et landsted i Toscana - Leie feriehus i Italia</title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="http://tornaia.com/xmlrpc.php">

<!-- code for IE -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style/css/IEsucks.css" />
<![endif]-->
<-- also add this -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This last one you can find the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) really useful, it is just a script to make html5 new tags work as they should in IE.

Well if it did work before and it doesnt now, it is a bit weird. but sometimes it is just catche that it was working before and now it is expired, but if you really wanna keep control of your source try either [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Dont forget to create the files ;) and add the required styles to make look good on IE..

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry, but I'm kind of a noob at this, where should I put this code? 

And another thing that I can't quite understand: I didn't have this problem two months ago, and I haven't changed or updatet the theme since. How is it possible that all of a sudden there is missing some parts of the code?

Comment: @MartinFlottorpPaus I just updated the answer, if you have any question ask ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks again.

I tried to do what you said, but I don't think that it changed anything. Anyway, here's what I did: I changed the header.php-file from this (http://pastebin.com/9qRhCcvw) to this  (http://pastebin.com/94ud1TPa), inserting the codes you suggested. Do I also need to create the IEsucks.css - file? Or did I place the codes in the wrong place?

Comment: @Marteens but you need to change the path to those files and create them and add the proper style for it, those that are wrong in IE, and `html5shiv` just google for it, it is a javascript library to add html5 tags in old browsers, since you have wordpress the path for the file will look something like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>path/to/style/css/IEsucks.css" />`  but you need to add the CSS to it and make it work, it is not magic ;)

Comment: Hehe, ok. Too bad it's not magic, that would be so much easier ;)  I will give it a try, and I'll let you know how it goes. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem, but remember to update the path to the files, and that path it is assuming that this file it is located inside the template folder, also remember to add some styles to the file ;) 2

Comment: It gets more complicated. I created a sub directory (http://tornaia.com/testpage/), and I activated the same child-theme that I use on my main site.. So the problems should be the same on the two sites, right? But the sub directory - site is working just like it should. Just like my main (http://tornaia.com) site was working some months ago. 

This mean that it's something else that's causing the error, right? Or is still the missing css?

Comment: But now, when I activated all of the plugins I use at the other site, I got the same problem.. No I'm gonna deactivat one at the time.. hopefully it will show me where the problem lies..

Comment: I found the issue! It was a plugin that I just needed to update! And now I think it works! =)

Comment: Yep! Thanks for helping me out anyway! :)